# Login Based on ip

Tags: login, user-roles

I have to create an internal site for company. So I have to restrict all people out of the company to have a login. And all people from the company need to access the site without a login

Comment: access to the site or logged in access to the site? Can you be clearer/more explicit/specific?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.